# Bring me a book in the top drawer

Tags: grammar

1. Bring me a book in the top drawer.
2. Bring me the book in the top drawer.
3. Bring me books in the top drawer.
4. Bring me the books in the top drawer.﻿

---

Are they all grammatical? Would you let us know the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst all of them are grammatically correct, numbers #3 and #4 have a different meaning as they are *plural*. However, all of them are seldom used in conversation, for the reason that “in” in your sentence would tend to be replaced with “from”. The sentences you are more likely to hear are:

> - Bring me a book **from** the top drawer.
> - Bring me the book **from** the top drawer.
> - Bring me books **from** the top drawer.
> - Bring me the books **from** the top drawer.

The difference in meaning is that “a” implies that the person wants no specific book, and “the” implies a specific book that has been pre-determined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition, I'd also say that "the book(s) in the top drawer" implies that the book has been specified by its location. Whereas "bring me books in the top drawer" implies that you should take the drawer itself as well as the books.